# Wife Betrayal revealed by my employing organisation. Company wants me to either divorce my wife or leave the job! What to do now?

Tags: talaq, wife, cheating

My company, being very disciplined, has asked me to consider divorce or quitting the job because my wife was linked to one of my colleagues (betrayal or cheating was limited to phone calls / sms only with only one casual meet in public with a friend of hers). I have forgiven my wife and I can observe her changed behavior towards our life. She does not want to leave me. We have two small kids.  My parents do not want me to leave the job as I have earned a respectable position with formidable repute and bright scope for future. I want to live with my kids, my wife and with the will of Almighty Allah and my parents. What to do?  Please reply urgently.

Comment: What country do you work in? this goes against the law in many countries, a company does not have the right to interfere in your personal matters, unless your self-esteem enables you to think that this is okay(in that case it must be really low) this is oppression!

Comment: Why would your employer have a right in islam to weigh in on this?

Comment: No offense but the more I do read your question -as written- the more I get the feeling that it is primarily an advice-request and this is hardly on topic because it is attracting opinion-based answers.  It would be great if you could edit your answer to make it fit I strongly recommend you therefore to to read [ask] and to visit our [help]. You want three things: Keep your Job, keep your wife and the content of your parents. According your statement it is hard to fulfill.

Comment: My suggestion for an edition is: Can my employer ask me (or insist) to divorce my wife ....? Note that in working or active SE community your question would already have been closed (in less than 1h after posting it) only because the title which clearly conflicts with the SE policies! What to do now isn't an answerable question it is too broad, attracting opinion based answers! So please consider re-editing the title too! I know I might sound fussy, but I try to be fair as I take your concern seriously, else II would already voted to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you consider your job more important than your family, you shouldn't ruin your family because of it.

You said she doesn't want to leave you and you have two small kids, it's up to you if you want to leave her or not.

> 29:60 And many a creature does not carry its provision; God provides for it, and for you. He is the Hearer, the Knowledgeable.

God stands with what's Right.

> 29:59 They are the ones who were patient, and put their trust in their Lord.

Comment: Nice reply,your first phrase with your Quranic references is substantial answer JazakAllah.